# Confused with Console.ReadLine() value in .NET 6.0. while press the [Enter] without any other input

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am writing a console app with some basic function to let user have input and react based on user input.
In previous(.net 3.1), I can do things like this:

```
string str=Console.ReadLine();
if(str==""){
     Console.WriteLine("do this");
}
else {
     Console.WriteLine("do that");
}
```

Since this is a new OS I just try to install .net-6.0 without thinking too much.
But, due to some update in .net-6.0, the return type of Console.ReadLine() is now string? which is nullable and the code will become as follow:

```
string? str=Console.ReadLine();
if(str==""){
     Console.WriteLine("do this");
}
else {
     Console.WriteLine("do that");
}
```

Since I want to get input from user I can ignore the warning here to use the same coding as .net3.1, will the  `string? str=Console.ReadLine()` be null and cause nullreference exception. Or in what cause I can generate null from Console.ReadLine();

Comment: If you redirect input to your program, when Console.ReadLine cannot read more input because the redirected input has been consumed, then Console.ReadLine will return null.

Comment: If you want the if-then part to react to "nothing entered or no more text to be retrieved" you should instead use `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns `null` when the input is coming from a piped / redirected STDIN (rather than the interactive console), and the redirected stream reaches the end; as such, `Console.ReadLine()` *can* return `null`, and always could.

What you're seeing is a c# 8 feature: nullable reference types - where `string?` simply formalizes this to mean "a string reference that we anticipate to be null", as opposed to `string` which means "a string reference that should never be null". The key point here is: the return **did not change** - simply: the compiler is now recognizing that `null` is a possibility that you should consider.

The following program will take a piped input, read it to the end, and write the number of lines found:

```cs
int count = 0;
while (Console.ReadLine() is not null) count++;
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

when used, for example (from `cmd`):

```
MyExe < somefile
```

However, when used in an interactive terminal: it will never end until you hard kill it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0), the method only returns `null` if no more input is there:

> The next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available.

Nevertheless, it's good to check for `null` anyway:

```cs
string? str=Console.ReadLine();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
     Console.WriteLine("do this");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("do that");
}
```

Alternately if you are absolutely sure there won't be null, just use [`! (null-forgiving) operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)