# Having trouble fixing null reference errors

Tags: c#

Im very new to C# and I am trying to complete my assignment but I came across some errors that I don't understand how to fix or even what they are implying.

```
using System;
public class Assignment1B
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string item_one, itemtwo;
        int itemone_quantity, itemtwo_quantity;
        float itemone_cost, itemtwo_cost, itemone_total, itemtwo_total;

        // Asking first item
        Console.Write("What are you buying? ");
        item_one = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("How many? ");
        itemone_quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("What do they cost? ");
        itemone_cost = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Asking second item
        Console.Write("What else are you buying? ");
        itemtwo = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("How many? ");
        itemtwo_quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("What do they cost? ");
        itemtwo_cost = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Math
        itemone_total = itemone_quantity * (float)itemone_cost;
        itemtwo_total = itemtwo_quantity * (float)itemtwo_cost;

        // Listing everything
        Console.WriteLine("Your list:");
        Console.WriteLine("--------");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", item_one, itemone_quantity);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", itemone_cost, itemone_total);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", itemtwo, itemtwo_quantity);
        Console.Write("{0} ({1})", itemtwo_cost, itemtwo_total);
    }
}
```

The assignment wants me to asks you for the name, quantity, and price of two grocery store items. Then display them as a list.

What I have tried:
I have tried looking up the error codes individually to try and see if I can find an example to get a better understanding of why I am getting the error but I haven't found anything that deeply explains everything. Sorry I am still learning and I am open to any advice or tips.

Errors that I have:

> item_one = Console.ReadLine(); Warning CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type
> itemone_quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 's' in 'int int.Parse(string s)'.
> itemone_cost = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 's' in 'float float.Parse(string s)'.
> itemtwo = Console.ReadLine(); Warning CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
> itemtwo_quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 's' in 'int int.Parse(string s)'.
> itemtwo_cost = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 's' in 'float float.Parse(string s)'.

Comment: there are hundreds of thousand hits on google. Did you even try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect warning Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069203/incorrect-warning-converting-null-literal-or-possible-null-value-to-non-nullable)

Comment: You might also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271865/confused-with-console-readline-value-in-net-6-0-while-press-the-enter-with and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370565/resharper-says-that-console-readline-returns-null-value

Answer (score 0):

You should change the variable names to be more descriptive and related to grocery items, such as `itemOneName`, `itemOneQuantity`, `itemOnePrice`, `itemTwoName`, `itemTwoQuantity`, and `itemTwoPrice`.

In the prompts for item one, use the appropriate variable names instead of `"What are you buying?"` `"How many?"`, and `"What do they cost?"`

Similarly, for item two, use the appropriate variable names instead of `"What else are you buying?"` `"How many?"`, and `"What do they cost?"`.

try changing the output section, change the format to display the list of items in a clearer way, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your list:");
Console.WriteLine("--------");
Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, Quantity: {1}, Price: {2}, Total: {3}", itemOneName, itemOneQuantity, itemOnePrice, itemOneQuantity * itemOnePrice);
Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, Quantity: {1}, Price: {2}, Total: {3}", itemTwoName, itemTwoQuantity, itemTwoPrice, itemTwoQuantity * itemTwoPrice);
```

something like this in the end?

```
using System;
public class Assignment1B
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string itemOneName, itemTwoName;
        int itemOneQuantity, itemTwoQuantity;
        float itemOnePrice, itemTwoPrice, itemOneTotal, itemTwoTotal;

        // Asking first item
        Console.Write("What is the name of the first item? ");
        itemOneName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("How many of {0} do you want? ", itemOneName);
        itemOneQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("What is the price of {0}? ", itemOneName);
        itemOnePrice = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Asking second item
        Console.Write("What is the name of the second item? ");
        itemTwoName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("How many of {0} do you want? ", itemTwoName);
        itemTwoQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("What is the price of {0}? ", itemTwoName);
        itemTwoPrice = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Math
        itemOneTotal = itemOneQuantity * itemOnePrice;
        itemTwoTotal = itemTwoQuantity * itemTwoPrice;

        // Listing everything
        Console.WriteLine("Your list:");
        Console.WriteLine("--------");
        Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, Quantity: {1}, Price: {2}, Total: {3}", itemOneName, itemOneQuantity, itemOnePrice, itemOneTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, Quantity: {1}, Price: {2}, Total: {3}", itemTwoName, itemTwoQuantity, itemTwoPrice, itemTwoTotal);
    }
}
```